# Overhead if GC for memory in the JVM vs Swift style ARC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

The company that I work in have a kind of very different viewpoints regarding the JVM development platform.

Based on this paper here - http://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf

They are saying that an oracle jvm requires 3-5x the memory overheead i.e to operate a 1GB JVM we require 3-5 GB of RAM extra to counteract the JVM overhead and swift style ARC is the answer to GC issues.

I have made some counter arguments that it was not a Oracle/Sun JVM that they conducted a study on and some experimental VM and ARC has its own problems like circular references.

Is there any research conducted on what exactly/approximately is the overhead of GC for memory in the JVM, I could not find any.

My questions summarized

1) Is there any visible overhead for GC. Cause the 3-5x cost of RAM seems to really unreasonable if the fact is true.

Also, big data applications such as Apache spark,hbase,cassandra operate in terabyte/petabyte memory scale. If there is such an overhead in GC why would they develop in such  a platform?

2) ARC is considered to be inferior to other runtime GC tracing algorithms. If this is true, it would also be helpful if there are any papers directly comparing the effects of ARC compile time malloc/free vs JVM GC runtime cleanup

There is a claim by Chris Lattner which says GC consumes 3-5x memory here - https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160208/009422.html

Comment: I think you're confusing RAM space and disk space when claiming that *"Apache spark,hbase,cassandra operate in terabyte/petabyte"*.

Comment: Well spark operates mostly in memory. No, I did not get confused, I am just saying memory matters a lot to those kind of big data apps.

Comment: Data apps can run with less than 1 GB and still handle 1 petabyte of data. You're asking about RAM use on a single server (GC in a JVM), so mentioning *petabyte* definitely makes it sound like you're confusing the issue.

Comment: Ok, maybe that was confusing, but what I meant is those applications are more memory intensive when compared to a regular web application. For example spark can do a map reduce job entirely in memory, so if this GC overhead is true then jobs with datasets such as 1 GB would require 6 GB (counting 5GB as the 5x overhead) to operate which does not sound normal to me.

Comment: That paper bases its argument on single-threaded environments. But data-processing applications are usually heavily parallel, which is a disadvantage for ARC because it has to use atomic ops to be thread-safe, which can be quite costly. The paper also does not cover reference counting, they basically have a chapter that they did not take smart pointers (which is a form of refcounting) into account.

Comment: see also http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285336/167788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any visible overhead for GC. Cause the 3-5x cost of RAM seems to really unreasonable if the fact is true.

This is most likely a misunderstanding. You can run a JVM where 99% of the heap is used, however it will GC regularly. If you give the application more memory, it will be able to work more efficiently. Adding more memory to the heap can improve throughput. I have seen this work up to about 3x. Except in extreme cases, you are unlikely to see any benefit in adding more.

> Also, big data applications such as Apache spark,hbase,cassandra operate in terabyte/petabyte memory scale. If there is such an overhead in GC why would they develop in such a platform?

When working with big data, you often use memory mapped files and off heap memory. This places the bulk of the data to be managed by the application not the GC. This is no different to how a data base written in C++ might operate.

> ARC is considered to be inferior to other runtime GC tracing algorithms.

I couldn't comment on how smart ARC is. Java doesn't place any restrictions on how the GC should operate, but the sub-text is; it has to at least handle circular references. Anything less is assumed to be unacceptable.

BTW Java uses malloc/free via direct ByteBuffers.

> jobs with datasets such as 1 GB

What makes a data set 1 GB. Compressed on disk it might be 100 MB. As raw uncompressed data it might be 1 GB. In memory as a data structure it might be 2 GB, and the throughput might be faster if you use say another 1 or 2 GB to work on that data structure.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about memory mapped files/direct memory access. Something that I learnt today.

Comment: Here is a claim by Chris Lattner which says that the JVM has to have 3-5x extra memory to operate smoothly. https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160208/009422.html . What is your taken on this

Comment: @WangLiqin you can use malloc/free in Java however there is many reason to not use them including the fact that Java allocation scales across multiple threads. Also the jit can put objects on the stack eliminating them even if his claim of 3x is correct it's only a problem on small, low power devices. When data sets are large you have other means of dealing with data, when data sets are small you are looking at wasting less than an hour of developer time in memory. You have consider how much your time is worth and be cost effective for the business you are working for.

Comment: @WangLiqin in short, 1 GB costs less than a Starbucks coffee. If you are running on a thousand devices this adds up in which case you spend a little more time optimising your code.

Comment: Understood, and there are issues in Swift ARC too, just wanted to have different views. Again thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Wang Liqin: that mail says “3-4x”, not 5x. However, that’s still nonsense, as that would imply that on a 32Bit JVM, which supports only slightly more than 1GB heap, actually using more than 250 to 300MB RAM would cause significant performance problems, but try to find an application of the last decade using that little memory. How did I even start the Eclipse IDE in those times? Besides, JVMs support different GC algorithms, rendering flat statements of that kind nonsensical, e.g. the “*the sweep pass touches almost all RAM in the process*” claim. Apparently, he never heard of “card marking”

Comment: @WangLiqin another way of reading the statement is that Java can benefit from giving it more than the minimum amount of memory but Swift cannot (which I suspect isn't true either)

Comment: It might be worth noting that the GC is smart enough to know, where object references can appear, e.g. if you allocate a `byte[]` array of ~2GB, it has no impact on the GC, as it knows that a `byte[]` array can’t contain object references, hence there’s nothing to traverse. So there’s not much difference to a direct buffer, only for the accounting, as the array still belongs to the used heap.

Comment: @Holger one difference is that direct buffers can be sparse in memory (not all page use main memory) and memory mapped files can be 10x main memory size provided the working set is small enough.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: there’s no formal aspect preventing a byte array implementation with the same properties. It’s an implementation detail of current OpenJDK/Oracle’s JVM not allowing heaps bigger than the physical memory.

Comment: @Holger In the future Java might support byte[] of 2 GB or larger as well.

Comment: Well, that would be the point, where the 2GB limitation of `ByteBuffer` should be lifted as well…

Comment: @Holger I have written an implementation for Java 6+ which does. I used it to created a 100 TB buffer using continuous virtual memory. ;) Wouldn't need to change the JVM, just the libraries.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is nothing smart about ARC it is pure dumb reference counting mechanism. That is why it releases objects as soon as they are no longer used, and that is why developer has to take care of strong reference cycles.

Comment: @WangLiqin When you talk about Lattner's statements you should also take into account that Swift is largely used on mobile devices (iOS) This is where ARC wins big time comparing to GC. With ARC you use just as much memory you need, not a byte more and deallocation  overhead is spread evenly resulting in smooth operation and user experience.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar,Holger : If you find time, please write a blog regarding that mail by Chris. Apparently bullshit tends to spread around the internet like wildfire.

Comment: @WangLiqin You are misinterpreting what has been said. 3-5x RAM overhead does not mean that under GC everything you do allocates 3-5x more memory, just that overall application will occupy more memory between GC collection cycles than it would be necessary under manual memory management (or ARC).

Comment: @WangLiqin For instance, if you load 10 MB (unpacked) image under GC system it will occupy 10 MB, not 30 MB or 50. If you load that same image under ARC it would also occupy 10 MB. But if you no longer need it and load another 10 MB image under GC your app will at that moment use 20 MB of memory, while ARC would immediately free first image and use only 10 MB after other image is loaded. If you load 3rd image GC app will now use 30 MB... and so on, unless, of course, GC gets triggered in the meantime.